# how to export headers using Qt pro files

Tags: qt, qt4, makefile

I've a project with following files

```
TestProject/api/apiheader1.h
TestProject/api/apiheader2.h
TestProject/src/apiimplementaton.cpp
TestProject/inc/apiimplementation.h
TestProject/TestProject.pro
```

When the project TestProject.pro is built headers apiheader1.h, apiheader2.h needs to be copied to /usr/include/TestLib/. Is it possible to do this by specifying it in project file TestProject.pro.?

Any pointers / links will be helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify, must it happen when it is built?  If that isn't important, you can fairly easily set up a system to move them when you type "make install".

Comment: Except that the Makefile is generated by qmake using the .pro file which is why he is asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this to the pro file... in qmake you can add extra targets...The copyheaders will get run once the target is built..

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copyheaders  
POST_TARGETDEPS += copyheaders  

copyheaders.commands += mkdir -p /usr/include/TestlLib  
copyheaders.commands += cp -f PATH_TO_HEADERS/apiheader1.h /usr/include/TestLib  
copyheaders.commands += cp -f PATH_TO_HEADERS/apiheader2.h /usr/include/TestLib
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to move the files? Moving source files around feels wrong.

As for doing it using qmake, you can use the system() function to simply cp the files in question. http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/qmake-function-reference.html#system-command

Comment: only headers are moved not the sources

Comment: Not sure what your commenting, you control what you move using the cp call. 

As for my first comment, moving files at all during build feels akward. You can use the gcc -I argument (qmake variable INCLUDE_DIRS) to add more directories to look for headers in instead.

Moving files means that you have to be extra careful when making changes and checking in things in your version control system.